# canvas rotate makes translate go in different direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have an image in a canvas which users can rotate and move, using the rotate() and translate() methods.

The moving works fine, until the image is rotated.
Once rotated, translate moves the canvas relative to its rotation.. how do I avoid this?

my code on 'mousemove':

```
var $canvas  = $('#viewport')[0];
var context  = $canvas.getContext('2d');

// Clear the canvas first
context.clearRect(0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.width);
context.save();

// Do any rotating first
// Move to center
context.translate($canvas.width/2, $canvas.height/2);
// Rotate
context.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180, $canvas.width, $canvas.width);
// Move back to top-left
context.translate(-$canvas.width/2, -$canvas.height/2);

// Move the canvas to dragged point
context.translate(translate_pos.x, translate_pos.y);

// Draw the image
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

context.restore();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? The order of these operations seems a bit unintuitive, you're moving to the center, rotating then moving back, but since you rotated, you're not getting to the top-left anymore.